# Remove all divs (with specific class) except the div (having same class) parenting a dropdown with particular id

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have a code stating:

   `$(".risk_main_div:not(#risk_1)").remove();`
2. The div `#risk_1` contains a *dropdown* whose *id* is fetched using this concept:

   `firstIDdrop = $(".input_field.criteria_risk").first().attr('id');`
3. Since *removal* of `#risk_1` is done *hard-codedly*, I want it to be achieved it like something like this

   `$(".risk_main_div:not([parent of firstIDdrop])").remove();`

How can I correct this code?

### HTML

Its a rough HTML like this,

```
<div id="risk_1" class="risk_main_div">
     <div id="risk_drp_cont_1">
         <select id="risk_mitigator_offer_1" class="input_field criteria_risk" multiple="" style="width: 302px; display: none;" name="risk_mitigator_offer_1[]">
     </div>    
     <div id="risk_wgt_cont_1">
          <input id="risk_weight_1" class="input_field" type="text" maxlength="3" style="color:#777777; width: 40px;" value="0" name="risk_weight_1">
     </div>
      <div id="risk_del_cont_1">
         <a id="delete_mitigator" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteRisk(1)"></a>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both">
</div>

<div id="risk_2" class="risk_main_div">
     <div id="risk_drp_cont_2">
         <select id="risk_mitigator_offer_2" class="input_field criteria_risk" multiple="" style="width: 302px; display: none;" name="risk_mitigator_offer_2[]">
     </div>    
     <div id="risk_wgt_cont_2">
          <input id="risk_weight_2" class="input_field" type="text" maxlength="3" style="color:#777777; width: 40px;" value="0" name="risk_weight_2">
     </div>
      <div id="risk_del_cont_2">
         <a id="delete_mitigator" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteRisk(2)"></a>
      </div>
      <div style="clear:both">
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector with [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
$(".risk_main_div:not(:has(#firstIDdrop))").remove();
```

if `firstIDdrop` is a variable

```
$(".risk_main_div:not(:has(#" + firstIDdrop +"))").remove();
```

```js
$(function() {
  $(".risk_main_div:not(:has(#firstIDdrop))").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="risk_main_div">1</div>
<div class="risk_main_div">2</div>
<div class="risk_main_div">3
  <select id="firstIDdrop">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="risk_main_div">4</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To find someone's parent I'd suggest you make a selector that first match any parent that is not matching the parent id you'd like to not match, then what you're looking for.

Something along these lines should work:

```
$("not:(" + firstIDdrop + ") .risk_main_div").remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can get the parent when fetching the `id` in the first place. Something like this:

```
var $parent = $(".input_field.criteria_risk").first();
$(".risk_main_div:not(#" + $parent.attr("id") + ")").remove();
```